# Polymer element templates gets removed after drag and drop

Tags: polymer

Im having a problem with an polymer element that gets dragged from one div to another.  It has some data in the list but once it gets dropped in the other div, those items do not show anymore.  When I look inside the array that contains the data bound to the list it still contains the data.  I thought that maybe the tamplate needs to be restamped but am not sure how.

Here is a link to a JSBin that illustrates the problem : 
http://jsbin.com/mimofadame/edit?html,output

Thanks

Comment: I've tested your bin on safari, chrome and firefox without any issues ... which browser and version you are using?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of chrome, and the latest polymer.

Answer (score 0):

I did a bower update, it seems that something got pushed that fixed it.

Thanks